# Mac OS X Zoom Button Hover Menu App

Tags: macos, osx-lion, user-interface

I saw today in a lecture at Uni a feature where hovering over the plus ('zoom') button presented a short horizontal menu of about four icons each of options of how to 'zoom' or maximize the content. Does anyone know what that app that does that is called?

Comment: Could this be part of the Accessibility framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for an app called 'Moom', it's very good!

[Link to Moom site](http://manytricks.com/moom/)